# SQL Server Logical Reads increased 10x in past week

Tags: sql, database-performance, windows-server-2022

I'm not an SQL DBA by any serious standard but I am trying to figure out why the logical reads have gone bonkers on a DB I have for a line of business app.
the image below shows a 10 x increase in logical reads? what could be causing that? Feel free to ask for any other info, as far as I can tell server performance metrics are fine CPU/Ram etc
The area highlighted in green is where I would like to get back to, as you can see the execution count has not really changed :-/

[SQL Query Tool - Overall Resource Consumption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q91B7.png)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The reads are coming from the application server(s) using the database. I would start there.

Comment: @GregAskew the application is on the same server, is there a way of monitoring the reads to a particular source/process?

Comment: We don't know what the application is or how to measure its performance or activity.